# How to add parent items to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i'm not looking for code but for some suggestion of how can i make something like a parent in RecyclerView.

I mean i have yet a main recyclerView (grey one on the screenshot) where i add items from other recyclerView (not shown on the screen) now i would be able like if i'm pressing on a item from main recyclerView and i press "varianti" it will open an alertDialog where i there is another recyclerView with a lot of item so if i press on one or more of that items that will add that item under the selected item from main recyclerView.

And when obv i delete the item from main recyclerView as "TORTILLA" that have to delet even the parent items from added "VARIANTI"

Here is a screenshot example of what i would to archive

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same List shared across the screens  , I guess you can reuse the ViewModel Object .

1. Create Fragments for both the screens .
2. Create a View Model with the List of Objects, that will hold all your common objects
3. Keep the Context of the Viewmodel for both Fragments same  - Probably under the same Activity .
4. You should also consider to keep storing the changes in a local DB . Possibly a Room DB .

A Better approach would be to have both views read data from a Live Data Object (Use it with a ViewModel Object).
Whenever there is a change , just update RoomDB/Sqllite  or any local Android DB . 
Your Database will be the single source of truth for all your UI .

The RecyclerView could use Databinding directly to read or Update The List of Objects directly

[image]

Comment: Actually i'm using 2 different lists, it's an app that simulate an "restoraunt order terminal" so in one list i have all the stuff from menu like "TORTILLA" when in the AlertDialog there are just variables like "WITH MORE CHEESE" or stuff like that and actually it's the same activity so there are just 1 screen

Comment: Ok , in that case wouldn't it be easy to just maintain a single ViewModel . Hold a Set of Objects under that and Get it synced with the DB . Wherever in your View you update , update directly the RoomDB . Since the View uses the LiveData object retrieved from DB , the update will immediately reflect .

If its just a temporary Object for menu , then you can just keep it in View model .Update DB only after confirmation.